# Creating MongoDB documents inside chained Promisified functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

An app runs a process every 15 minutes that creates many output files with the following format:

```
<timestamp>-<piece-code>.txt
```

All files created by the process will share the "timestamp" component but the "piece-code" will differ, meaning I have a relationship of **One** Timestamp to **Many** Pieces, that I want to save in mongodb as:

```
"Registry" { time: (numeric) }
"Piece" { file: (string), piece: (string), registry: (reference) }
```

In the process I want to find if a **timestamp** exists already before creating it to avoid duplicates, but my code seems to fail to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Registry = require('../model/Registry');
const Piece = require('../model/Piece');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

// Set up default mongoose connection
let mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/numbers';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});

//Get the default connection
let db = mongoose.connection;

// Bind connection to error event
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));


// Error handler
let error = (err) => {
  console.log("** Error: ", err);
  db.close();
};

// Finish routine
let finish = () => {
    console.log("I have finished");
    db.close();
};


// Create a number if it does not exist already
let newRegistry = (timestamp) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Registry.count({}).then((c) => { console.log(c) })

    // Does this Registry exist?
    Registry.findOne({ time: timestamp })
      .then((reg, err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        // Create when it does not exist
        if (!reg) {
          Registry.create({
            time: timestamp
          }).then((doc, err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            resolve(doc._id);
          })
          .catch(error);
        } else {
          // Else, resolve
          resolve(reg._id);
        }

      });
  });
}

let newPiece = (registryId, filename, piece) => {
  return Piece.create({
    registry: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(registryId),
    file: filename,
    piece: piece
  });

};

let createRegs = (files) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let promises = [];
    let total = files.length;
    for (let i=0; i<total; i++) {
      let fileAr = files[i].split("-");
      let time = fileAr[0];
      let piece = fileAr[1];

      let promise = newRegistry(time)
        .then((regId) => {
          return newPiece(regId, files[i], piece);
        });

      promises.push(promise);
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(error);
  });
}


// Register input time and file pieces: one "time" can have many "pieces"
let filenames = ["1512473256-e.txt", "1512471758-a.txt", "1512471892-a.txt", "1512471758-b.txt"];

// Must end up with 3 "Registry" and 4 "Piece" documents
createRegs(filenames)
  .then(finish)
  .catch(error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it worth to get rid from duplicating numbers in your array?
By doing something like this:

```
let filtered = [];
numbers.forEach((num) => {
  // in case we don't have such entity creating it
  if (!filtered.includes(num)) {
    filtered.push(num);
  }
  // in case we have just returning resolved promise
  return Promise.resolve();
});
```

And then create your entities in DB:

```
const promises = filtered.map(n => {
  Number.findOne({ number: n })
    .then(result => if(!result) {
      return Number.create({ number: n });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
Promise.all(promise).then(() => /* Doing what you want to do after saving */)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Well, this is just an example, on the real case the array is made up of filenames in the forma <timestamp>_<code>.txt, and I need to save many "codes" per "timestamp".

Comment: Oh, now I got it.
Try to make something like this 
Number.findOne({ number: n }).exec().then((result) => /* here is your code for checking if it is an empty result or not */)

Comment: No, nothing. Every "time" is created in the DB as if it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be this:

1. First I'd create a dictionary where keys would be the timestamp, and value would be an array with different pieces.
2. Once you have this dictionary, I'd treat each timestamp of the list

   - Look for the timestamp in the DB. Create it if it doesn't exist yet.
   - Loop through all pieces of the timestamp and add it to the database.

With this approach you avoid your concurrency problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Well, this is just an example, on the real case the array is made up of filenames in the forma <timestamp>_<code>.txt, and I need to save many "codes" per "timestamp".

Comment: I don't see how the example you wrote and your problem are exactly related. Maybe is better to create another question with the real problem and real code to understand it better. 
Sorry for not being more helpful

Comment: Hi again @David, I updated the question, I hope this is more specific. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now it's clear the whole picture. I have eddited my answer, check it and tell me if you anderstand.